# Curious about how to specify the number of core for MPI in order to get the fastest scientific computation

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp

I have been running several scientific program package in conjunction with MPI by using the following command

```
nohup mpirun -np N -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=M program.exe < input > output &
```

where the value of N and M depend on the physical CPU cores of my machine. For example, my machine has the specification like this

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                24
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-23
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    6
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          2
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 45
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2440 0 @ 2.40GHz
Stepping:              7
```

In this case, I first tried setting with N = 24 and M = 1, so the calculation ran very slowly. Then I changed N and M to 12 and 2 respectively. So I found that the latter had obviously provided me the fastest computation.

I was wondering that why did I set N & M are 12 and 2 provide more performance higher than the first case ?

Comment: Try N=2 and M=12, I think it gives the fastest code. Why? because OpenMP is designed for shared-memory while MPI is for distributed-memory.

Answer (score 2):

there is no absolute rule on how to run MPI+OpenMP application.
the only advice is not to run an OpenMP process on more than one socket
(OpenMP was designed for SMP machines with flat memory access, but today, most systems are NUMA)

then just experiment.

some apps run best in flat MPI (e.g. one thread per task), while some other work best with one MPI task per socket, and all available cores for OpenMP.

last but not least, if you run more than one OpenMP thread per MPI task, make sure your MPI library bound the MPI tasks as expected.
for example, if you run with 12 OpenMP threads but MPI bind tasks to one core, you will end up doing time sharing and performance will be horrible.
or if you run with 12 OpenMP threads, and MPI task was bound to 12 cores, make sure the 12 cores are on the same socket (and not 6 on each socket)

Comment: Most openmp applications run well on Xeon with 1 thread per core.  A likely   possibility is 1 mpi rank per socket. As stated above, you need affinity set so each mpi process has exclusive access to its group of cores, each thread stays on 1 cpu, and threads are spread evenly across cores.

Comment: Among relevant settings is omp_places=cores, with corresponding num_threads, as you appear to run on Linux where current openmp supports this.

Comment: on KNL, some applications run best flat mpi with 2 tasks per core (e.g. 2 hyperthreads per task). as stated above, optimal performance can be achieved when binding OpenMP threads via the OpenMP runtime and within what was inherited from MPI.

Comment: Thank you. @GillesGouaillardet

Answer (score 1):

There is no general rule about this because, most of the time, this performance is dependent on the computation properties of the application itself.

Applications with coarse synchronization granularity may scale well using plain MPI code (no multithreading).

If the synchronization granularity is fine, then using shared memory multithreading (such as OpenMP) and placing all the threads in a process close to each other (in the same socket) becomes more important: synchronization is cheaper and memory access latency is critical.

Finally, compute-bound applications (performance is limited by the processor) are likely not to benefit from hyper-threading at all, since two threads sharing a core contend for the functional units it contains. In this case, you may find applications that perform better using N=2 and M=6 than using N=2 and M=12.

Answer (score 0):

indeeed there is no absolute rule on how to run MPI+OpenMP application.
I agree with all Gilles said.
so I want to talk about the CPU in your case.

in the specification you give, it shows the system enables hyper-thread.
but this not always helps. your computer has 12 physical cores in fact.
so I advice you try some combinations that make M * N = 12 to 24, 
like 12*1, 6*2, 6*3
which one is best, depends on how well your application.